# Problem installing SSL Certificade in Go Lang with Echo framework (Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.)

Tags: go, ssl, https, go-echo

I have build a Go server using Echo framework, i get TLS certificades and a domain name, but when i try a request i get the message `"Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server."` and when i try acces the server from the IP address of the EC2 using the port 443, it says that the connection is not secure:

[image]

And when i change the server to the port 80 to acces through the domain name, i get the following error:

[image]

I'm starting the server using the StartTLS func

```
e.Logger.Fatal(e.StartTLS(":80", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/anltcsprod.enrtt.com/fullchain.pem", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/anltcsprod.enrtt.com/privkey.pem"))
```

Is it something wrong with my domain or certificade?

Comment: If your certificate has the domain name, then you have to access the site using the domain name. If you access using port 80, the default protocol is http, not https. Use port 443, and access using domain name

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks, now i use it at port 443 but still i get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to connect using the domain :(

Comment: Are you connecting to `https://domain`, or `http://domain`? If you are doing http, then it will go to :80.

Comment: True! it works! my bad haha i assumed that writing the domain in the browser by default was HTTPS but when i write all the address using the HTTPS it worked!
Thank you @BurakSerdar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port 80, by default, communicates over HTTP. 443 is reserved for HTTPS traffic. Assuming nothing else is wrong, you should be able to simply change your `e.StartTLS()` to this:

```golang
e.Logger.Fatal(e.StartTLS(":443", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/anltcsprod.enrtt.com/fullchain.pem", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/anltcsprod.enrtt.com/privkey.pem"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For example `localhost:4000`

Instead use `https://localhost:4000`